# Max7219 7-segment display not working

Tags: arduino-mega, max7219

when I connect VCC pin to the 5V and GND to the GND on the Arduino MEGA, then sometimes the display glows and sometimes it doesn't. It kinda looks like some contacts are bad because it starts to work mostly when I move it somehow, but I'm sure the problem is not in contacts as they defintely touch.

I also measured voltage on the display and it showed correctly ~5V.

Where could be the problem? Thanks

//Edit

I am using those displays to build simple autopilot panel for MSFS20 using MobiFlight. There is not any code, you just have to define what pins you connected and that's it. But even if it turns on, then all the leds stay on.

There might be a problem since I soldered the pins into the display so I could damage the board, it's a cheap one from China. Is there a way how to test if it's a board problem?

Comment: just because the two components touch, it does not mean that there is an electric connection ... corrosion on component leads can have insulating quality ... the 5 V reading is meaningless for a bad connection ... you would read 5 V if nothing was conected to the power pins

Comment: Well I have a 3 of these displays and they all behave same

Comment: I read 5V on the display, not on the arduino

Comment: you are not understanding .. a reading of 5 V is not an indication of the component fitness ... a burned out light bulb still has full voltage at its base

Comment: it sounds like the serial data line may have a problem

Comment: Oh I see, what can I do then?

Comment: @Elayer213 Sorry, currently we cannot really help you. We can just guess, because you didn't gave much information. Please show your circuit and also show, how you have connected everything (as jsotola wrote, touching doesn't mean good connection, especially if data should run over that connection). Please also show the code in your question. You can edit it and add all these information